# Recursively Search Dirs & SubDirs And Numerically Rename Files

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am attempting to recursively scan a directory and rename all `.jpg and .jpeg` files in the dirs (and sub dirs) to a numeric naming convention.

I have this syntax

```
get-childitem -Recurse -path C:\Users\jsimpson\Desktop\Test123 | where {($_.extension -eq '.jpg') -or ($_.extension -eq '.jpeg') | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘MyFile{0}.txt’ -f $nr++)}
```

However - this gives me an error of

> Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
> ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

I am sure this is something mundane on my end that I am overlooking - but what would be the proper syntax to numerically rename all files?

**EDIT**
Current filename is `P1870426.jpeg` I want to rename it to `1.jpeg`

The files are all an import from a digital camera and Since the files have garbage names - I am basically wanting a way to import them into a program and have the files remain in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, there's a `}` missing to close `Where` :

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:\Users\jsimpson\Desktop\Test123' | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match 'jpg|jpeg'} | ForEach-Object {
    $newFile = "{0}$($_.Extension)" -f $nr++
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $newFile -Force
}
```

Comment: good catch.  I notice one other issue.  I am specifying .jpg or .jpeg in the WHERE but in the MyFile I am specifying .txt - how can I change that to specify .jpg or .jpeg?

Comment: This presents an error of Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'P1870445.jpeg' does not exist.
At line:2 char:5
+     Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("MyFile{0}$($_.extension)" -f $nr++)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand  --- but the file does exist/?

Comment: Just did a copy/paste of edited answer and still getting error:  Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'P1870445.jpeg' does not exist.
At line:3 char:5
+     Rename-Item $_ -NewName $newFile -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Can you change `Rename-Item $_` by `Rename-Item $_.FullName`?

Comment: that appends the numeric value to the end of the filename.  I was wanting to totally rename the filename to a numeric value

Comment: I edited the answer, now it should be what you're looking for

Comment: The edit syntax gives me the below error: Cannot convert value ".jpeg" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:2 char:5
+     $newFile = ($nr++) + $_.Extension
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger

Comment: Ooook answer edited. It should be good else I'm quiting Powershell... I now have a headache :-p

Comment: Sorry for the multiples edits, I was not in my best day ;-)